# post data using python with help of multipart/form-data option

Tags: python, json

I am new to rest api. I am trying to post data to service. recently I am doing it through postman tool and it's working.

Now I want to do it using python so I am copying postman's python code it's working, but is there any other way to send data using python

like here my python script

```
import requests

url = "http://http:/localhost:3200/api/log"

payload = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"ip\"\r\n\r\n235.23.14.242\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"\r\n\r\n{\n\t\t\"Main\": \n\t\t{\n\t\t   \"subfolder\" : \n\t\t\t{        \n\t\t\t   \"photos\" : \n\t\t\t\t{\n\t\t\t\t  \"January\" : \n\t\t\t\t\t[\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"name  Detail of photo\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"date  id of photo\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"location location detail\"\n\t\t\t\t\t],\n\t\t\t\t   \"February\" : \n\t\t\t\t\t[\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"name  Detail of photo\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"date  id of photo\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"location location detail\"\n\t\t\t\t\t]\n\t\t\t\t}\n}\n}\n}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--"
headers = {
'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
'cache-control': "no-cache",
'Postman-Token': "5466e12e-b5d8-4326-a75c-8c9502963ed5"
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

this code is working but here I have to put json data in payload . can I do it other way ?? like load json file in string and pass that string in payload . Actually I tried it but it's not working like this

```
import requests

url = "http://http:/localhost:3200/api/log"
str="235.23.14.242"
files={
    "Main":
    {
       "subfolder" :
        {
           "photos" :
            {
              "January" :
                [
                    "name  Detail of photo",
                    "date  id of photo",
                    "location location detail"
                ],
               "February" :
                [
                    "name  Detail of photo",
                    "date  id of photo",
                    "location location detail"
                ]
            }
 }
 }
 }
 payload = {"ip":str,"file":files}
 headers = {
 'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=----  WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
 'cache-control': "no-cache",
 'Postman-Token': "5466e12e-b5d8-4326-a75c-8c9502963ed5"
  }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Is there any other way to send this type of data ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found ans...

```
import requests

url = "http://http:/localhost:3200/api/log"
strr="235.23.14.242"
files={
    "Main":
    {
       "subfolder" :
        {
           "photos" :
            {
              "January" :
                [
                    "name  Detail of photo",
                    "date  id of photo",
                    "location location detail"
                ],
               "February" :
                [
                    "name  Detail of photo",
                    "date  id of photo",
                    "location location detail"
                ]
            }
 }
 }
 }

 fl=str(files)
 payload = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; " \
      "name=\"ip\"\r\n\r\n"+strr+"\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; " \
      "name=\"file\"\r\n\r\n"+fl+"\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--"
 headers = {
 'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=----  WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
 'cache-control': "no-cache",
 'Postman-Token': "5466e12e-b5d8-4326-a75c-8c9502963ed5"
  }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Thanks for response..